# Change OnMylocationButtonClick zoom in Google Maps v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to change the zoom level when I click on my Location button but it is always getting default zoom value.

Guess what, the zoom doesn't work only in Animate part. If I use moveCamera it changes the zoom level to what I have specified.

Here is what I am trying:

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() 
    {
      Log.e("Inside","Click part");
      LatLng ll = new LatLng(curlat,curlong);
      CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20);
      googleMap.animateCamera(update);  
      return false;
    }
});
```

Not sure what is wrong here in the animate part?

Comment: Do you have other listeners that also change the camera and maybe pick up the current zoom level. If they run during animation they will pick and fix the current zoom level, while this will not happen when the camera is directly moved without animation.

Comment: @user2808624: I don't have any other listener. I used to have googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); but I have disabled it now and still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return true instead of false. Otherwise the map performs the default action in addition, which most probably (I did not check in detail) includes to move to the current position (same as your ll) but using the "current" zoom level. The current zoom level has not yet changed much, if you animate the camera. But it has changed completely if you move the camera directly without animation.

Comment: Change false to true. This was the problem. Thanks a lot!